# PageMethods and Application_Error - ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax, webmethod

My application is setup to log exceptions and this is done in the `Application_Error` method. I've started adding Page Methods (which are static). Exceptions in Page Methods do not trigger the `Application_Error` method in `Global.asax.cs`

What is the best practice to catch these exceptions?

PS: I am using JQuery ajax to call PageMethods

Comment: Hey Dusty check this link out I think it will help you : http://geekswithblogs.net/pavelka/archive/2005/09/05/HowToCreateAGlobalExceptionHandlerForAWebService.aspx

Comment: @Rick - I am not using web services, but calling page methods. I assume this article applies to me as well?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look into [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).  Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't need to.

Comment: Unfortunately, this application already uses a different error handling framework/mechanism and replacing it is not an option at this time.

Comment: And ELMAH would not log this exception anyway because, as Rick explains, the exception is being caught and handled and so cannot be captured by Elmah.